# Displaying SPARQL Output in Column rather than Row

Tags: excel, format, output, sparql

I have several SPARQL queries like the following:

```
SELECT ?mept ?uspt ?sapt ?rept ?sspt 
WHERE {{SELECT (COUNT(?mep) AS ?mept)
    WHERE {codo:MiddleEastCluster codo:hasMember ?mep.}}
    {SELECT (COUNT(?usp) AS ?uspt)
    WHERE {codo:USACluster codo:hasMember ?usp.}}
    {SELECT (COUNT(?sap) AS ?sapt)
    WHERE {codo:SouthAmericaCluster codo:hasMember ?sap.}}
    {SELECT (COUNT(?rep) AS ?rept)
    WHERE {codo:RestOfEuropeCluster codo:hasMember ?rep.}}
    {SELECT (COUNT(?ssp) AS ?sspt)
    WHERE {codo:SouthernStatesCluster codo:hasMember ?ssp.}}}
```

The actual query is much larger, I shortened it for this example. I take this information and then put it into Excel to create bar and pie charts illustrating our data. As this (and other queries) currently work they display the results in a row like this:

```
?mept  ?uspt  ?sapt  ?rept  ?sspt

 515    7       5     22      481
```

I would prefer that it was formatted as a column like this:

```
?mept 515
?uspt 7
?sapt 5
?rept 22
?sspt 481
```

That would make it easier to copy and paste the data directly into Excel. Is there a simple way to do this with SPARQL? I've found examples online that do much more complicated things like directly output the data from SPARQL to Excel. I don't need anything that sophisticated, just an easy way to format the output as a column rather than a row.

Comment: it is indeed possible. Just use a `UNION` between the subqueries and reuse variable names in all subqueries, i.e. it should be like this:`SELECT  ?type ?cnt
WHERE
  {   { SELECT  (COUNT(?mep) AS ?cnt) ("mep" AS ?type)
        WHERE
          { codo:MiddleEastCluster
                      codo:hasMember  ?mep
          }
      }
    UNION
      { SELECT  (COUNT(?usp) AS ?cnt) ("usp" AS ?type)
        WHERE
          { codo:USACluster
                      codo:hasMember  ?usp
          }
      }
  }` - it's untested indeed.

Comment: but, I think your query can be made much more compact: `SELECT  ?type (COUNT(?member) AS ?cnt)
WHERE
  { VALUES ( ?cluster ?type ) {
      ( codo:MiddleEastCluster "mep" )
      ( codo:USACluster "usp" )
    }
    ?cluster  codo:hasMember  ?member
  }
GROUP BY ?cluster ?type` - no need for all the subqueries, just add more tuples to the `VALUES` clause

Comment: Thanks. I knew there was a better way to reuse those names, for some reason I wasn't getting it. You've been of great help, I really appreciate it. I'm working on my own and very new to SPARQL so your feedback has been incredibly useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comments, revised query --

```
SELECT                        ?type
       ( COUNT ( ?member ) AS ?cnt) 
WHERE 
  { VALUES  ( ?cluster               ?type ) 
      {     ( codo:MiddleEastCluster "mep" )
            ( codo:USACluster        "usp" )
      }     
    ?cluster  codo:hasMember  ?member 
  } 
GROUP BY ?cluster ?type
```